# Nil and Nilpotent Modules

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, modules, definition, noncommutative-algebra

Is there any definition for a nil or nilpotent $R$-module when $R$ is a ring with identity? I have searched the web for this purpose, but to no avail, and I appreciate in advance any suggestion or leading remark in this regard.

Comment: I see dozens of hits on Google for "nilpotent module". You say they don't work for you somehow? Could you comment on why they don't work?

Comment: Hi @rschwieb, thanks for your comment! I meant I haven't hit any!! Could you please introduce the relevant site(s)?

Comment: They are listed [here](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=%22nilpotent%20module%22)(?)